# Building a webpack project with a local sub module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I've developing a react component and for demo purpose I've created a react app so that I could test out the module I'm developing. So I've got a separate module which is a react module and I've used `npm link` to link the module to my project. following is the package json of the module.

**package json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "Imesh Chandrasiri",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack config**

const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                }
            }
        },{
            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        },{
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
            options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
            },
        },{
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|cur|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: ['url-loader'],
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'style.css'})
    ],
    externals: {
        'react': 'commonjs react'
    }
};
```

Using this config I've npm linked the module to my project which have the following package json and webpack config.

**package json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Imesh Chandrasiri",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader']
        },{
            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        }
      ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true
    }
  };
```

**Problem**

So this setup works fine and when I change a file in the module, it re compiles the in the project and reflects the change. The question is, the project gives me warnings in the console and the recompile time is so high.

```
WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  index.js (16.3 MiB)
  0.5721d2929929bd15755f.hot-update.js (15 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (31.3 MiB)
      index.js
      0.5721d2929929bd15755f.hot-update.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

What is the reason for such a warning? Is there anything I could do to improve the build time and avoid the warnings which is shown in the console.?

Answer (score 1):

```
WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment. You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
```

To get rid of this warning you need to set the `mode` option explicitly.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development', // <- Add this line
    entry: './src/index.js',

    // The rest of your code
```

---

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  index.js (16.3 MiB)
  0.5721d2929929bd15755f.hot-update.js (15 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (31.3 MiB)
      index.js
      0.5721d2929929bd15755f.hot-update.js

WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

This is because the final output files are tremendously big ... `16.3 MiB`, `15 MiB` and `31.3 MiB`. OMG!!!
Imagine every visitor to your website has to download `31.3 MiB` in order to view your website. May be the Internet infrastructure of your country is too good compared to the rest of the world. In my country it would take minutes to to download your website. Maybe the browser caching mechanism would save you a bit but not too much.

I cannot give you a guarantee-to-work solution because it highly depends on your project setup and it will be too big to fit in an answer here. But I can give you a suggestion of using `code-spliting` and this link to webpack documentation on it: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ . It was mentioned in the warning as well so you can trust it.

Basically, the idea is that you split your code into multiple `js` files. And if it only requires a `js` file whose size is `200 Kib` to render the home page we will only load it. The rest can wait and be loaded on demand.

I suggest you try setting up webpack `code-spliting` following the documentation and comeback here with another questions on it if any.

Comment: The thing is my project is not that large. The module I develop consists maximum 10 files and the project has only one js file which is invoking the module.

Comment: That is extra-ordinarily strange to me. I wonder how much code can a `16.3 MiB` js file contain. The biggest single output file I could create with Webpack was `2.3 MiB`. That included my code and about more than 20 npm packages.